# Can we define module namespace for a file that exist at the same directory level as rewrite.xqy?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a file that exist at the same level as `rewrite.xqy` i.e. it doesn't exist inside a particular directory. When i am declaring a `module namespace` for it, I get the following error-

```
<error:message>Cannot evaluate library module</error:message>
<error:format-string>XDMP-EVALLIBMOD: Cannot evaluate library module:
```

What is the logic behind this as when I remove `module namespace` it works just fine. These are the starting lines of my file-

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
module namespace adv = "http://***/***/adv"; 
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" 
  at "/Marklogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">',
xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html; charset=utf-8"),
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 3):

When you define a module namespace, your module is expected to be a [library module](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_26329) with a collection of functions. You don't "run" a library module though. If you attempt to run this code, for example by pasting into QConsole, you will get the **XDMP-EVALLIBMOD** error.

A [main module](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_57090) is expected to be executed as an XQuery program. Remove the module namespace `module namespace adv = "http://***/***/adv";`, and it will execute without error.

Or you can insert the code as a library module with the logic enclosed as the body of a function, import that module in a main module and call the function.

Comment: And if you're just trying to make that namespace available for use in the main module, do this: `declare namespace adv = "http://***/***/adv";`.

Answer (score 1):

The error

```
<error:message>Cannot evaluate library module</error:message>
<error:format-string>XDMP-EVALLIBMOD: Cannot evaluate library module:
```

Means you are attempting to directly evaluate your code/module not import it.
How are you getting this error ?
For a xquery module, you cannot invoke it directly, you must import it in another file (usually the one you are invoking).

XQuery does not allow a single file to be both a main entry point and a module.
When you say it 'works just fine'  -- thats a good place to stop.